# Change variable based on which element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, var

It is possible to change variable inside function which is based on element is user clicks?
In my case this will fully work for one kind of menu but I need two fully identical menu 
with one difference - 
second click handler must load toggleDrawer with changed $sidebar to $navbar variable.

```
    /*
    Variables
    */

    var $sidebar = $('#sidebar'),  
        $navbar = $('#navbar'),
        drawerOpen = false,

    /*
    Functions
    */

    closeDrawer = function() {
        drawerOpen = false;
        $body.css('overflow','').removeClass('sidebar-open');
        $sidebar.removeClass('open');
        $sidebar.animate({'right':'-50%'},{duration:300});
        $(this).hide();

    },

    openDrawer = function() {
        drawerOpen = true;
        $body.addClass('sidebar-open').css('overflow','hidden');
        $sidebar.addClass('open');
        $sidebar.animate({'right':'0%'},{duration:300});                
    },

    toggleDrawer = function() {
        if (drawerOpen) {
            closeDrawer();
        }else{
            openDrawer();
        }
    },

    /*
    Bind Events
    */

    $document.on('click', '.drawer-toggle-sidebar', function(event){
        toggleDrawer();
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $document.on('click', '.drawer-toggle-navbar', function(event){
        toggleDrawer();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: There's not need to do that. Just add a parameter to the function to know what element you are manipulating openDrawer($sidebar);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the above comment, and show an example:

Here are your functions with passing in the element you wish to open/close:

```js
/*
    Functions
    */

    closeDrawer = function(drawer) {
        drawerOpen = false;
        $body.css('overflow','').removeClass('sidebar-open');
        drawer.removeClass('open');
        drawer.animate({'right':'-50%'},{duration:300});
        $(this).hide();

    },

    openDrawer = function(drawer) {
        drawerOpen = true;
        $body.addClass('sidebar-open').css('overflow','hidden');
        drawer.addClass('open');
        drawer.animate({'right':'0%'},{duration:300});                
    },

    toggleDrawer = function(drawer) {
        if (drawerOpen) {
            closeDrawer(drawer);
        }else{
            openDrawer(drawer);
        }
    },
```

And your bind events:

```js
/*
    Bind Events
    */

    $document.on('click', '.drawer-toggle-sidebar', function(event){
        toggleDrawer(event.currentTarget);
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $document.on('click', '.drawer-toggle-navbar', function(event){
        toggleDrawer(event.currentTarget);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

You could even combine the two on click events into one and just pass in the currentTarget.

I hope this helps.